# Actionscript making intro of a game

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in full classes. so the timeline is empty. But I want to use another scene for the game intro, after the intro, it will proceed to the main menu of the game which I have created. Anyone got an idea? I haven't found any since a week ago... I don't really know about how to operate scenes from code in classes. Please help. Thanks!

Here is the main code :

```
package
{   
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public var field:Array;
    //CALL EVERY CLASS
    public var _money:Money = new Money();
    public var _gold:Gold;
    public var _hero:Hero;
    public var _enemy:Enemy;
    private var _pause:MovieClip = new Pause();
    private var pauseLayer:MovieClip = new PauseLayer();
    private var ts:TitleScreen;


    public function Main():void
    {
        ts = new TitleScreen();
        addChild(ts);
    }

    //GAME FUNCTION
    public function onStage():void
    {

        _hero = new Hero(this);
        _enemy = new Enemy(this);
        _gold = new Gold(this);

        setupField();

        _gold.goldSet(stage);
        _money.addText(stage);
        _hero.displayHero(stage);
        _enemy.displayEnemy(stage);
        setPause();
        _pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseGame);
    }


    private function setPause():void
    {
        addChild(_pause);
        _pause.x = 620;
        _pause.y = 50;
        _pause.buttonMode = true;
    }

    private function pauseGame (e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.frameRate = 0;
        addChild(pauseLayer);
        pauseLayer.alpha = 0.5;
        pauseLayer.parent.setChildIndex(pauseLayer,numChildren-1);
    }

    //SET UP FIELD ARRAY
    private function setupField():void 
    {
        var fieldSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
        addChild(fieldSprite);
        fieldSprite.graphics.lineStyle(4);

        field=new Array();

        for (var a:int=0; a<6; a++) 
        {
            field[a]=new Array();
            for (var b:int=0; b<10; b++) 
            {
                field[a][b]=0;
            }
        }
        //DRAW  FIELD
        for (var i:int=0; i<5; i++) 
        {
            for (var j:int=0; j<9; j++) 
            {
               fieldSprite.graphics.drawRect(75+65*j,50+75*i,65,75);                 
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Titlescreen class :

```
package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TitleScreen extends Sprite
{
    private var playBtn:MovieClip = new Resume();


    public function TitleScreen() 
    {
        playBtn.x = 50;
        playBtn.y = 50;
        playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Play);
    }



    private function Play(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

        trace("a");
    }

}

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be using wrapper `Sprite`s to hold each set of objects you probably want to be available as whole, say main menu, upgrades, storyline, etc etc. Then you just shift them in and out of display list to display corresponding "scene" with your `Main` class responsible of transition flow. But to do this you need to shift your game core functionality out of `Main` class into say `Game` class. That's how I have done the same thing in my game:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
        private var so:SharedObject;
        private var ui:UserInterface;
        private var ts:TitleScreen;
    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        ui = new UserInterface();
        ts = new TitleScreen();
        ts.newButtonClicked = newGame;
        ts.loadButtonClicked = loadGame;
        ui.gotoMapBehavior = wentToMap;
        addChild(ts);
    }
```

Here, `UserInterface` is a class that has gaming logic inside, and `TitleScreen` is a main menu class. The functions are callbacks in `Main`:

```
    private function newGame():void {
        removeChild(ts); // hide title
        if (!contains(ui)) addChild(ui);
        SoundManager.playMusic(SoundManager.MUSIC_LEVELSELECT);
    }
    private function loadGame():void {
        newGame();
        ui.loadBattle(); // this should make UI load the battle from shared object (either supplied or received by itself)
    }
    private function wentToMap():void {
        // we have just executed "go to map" from UI
        removeChild(ui);
        addChild(ts);
        checkSO();
        SoundManager.playMusic(SoundManager.MUSIC_INTRO);
    }
```

The actual gaming logic does not interact with `Main` at all, except for shared object which is common for the entire project, but the link is received normally via `SharedObject.getLocal(someName)`. The code is ugly, but could do for starters.

Comment: how to define ts.newButtonClicked as a mouse clicked event? I mean when  it's clicked it will go to the new game function in main class right? and I've edited my post, the button to play the game doesn't appear now. what's the problem there? thanks a lot anyway for answering!

Comment: That was a public property of a class, to not expose underlying button logic. You add to your class `public var newButtonClicked:Function`, then add an event listener within your class for some button with the code: `if (newButtonClicked) newButtonClicked();` This will make a call to whatever callback you'll assign with 0 arguments (you have to describe data flow for each callback yourself, some might require data to be passed through0.

Comment: I never know that function can be a var too. so the event listener will be newButtonClicked.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Event, Play) ? or how to do it? and from my edited code, why does the playBtn doesnt shpw up? can you please explain? sorry for late replay anyway. Thanks!

Comment: You never called `addChild(playBtn)` :) No, the add event listener statement remains as is, and the line `if (newButtonClicked!=null) newButtonClicked();` is added into the `Play` function.

Comment: wow everything works! thanks a lot! actually there's still one more thing I need to know, I think I will make the intro scene as animation from timeline with basic tweening things and stuffs. should I just make it as a movieClip and call it at the start and remove it when it goes to main menu? or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I think this is the right way to go. Also you can then dispatch events when your MC will stop at its end, so that `Main` will know and act. Read up on them if you need.

Comment: how to give the command to movieclip to start another function when it has ended? I don't know anything about dispatch events.. I was thinking of using for(a:int = 0;a<numberOfFrames in MovieClip; a++) in enterframe. so when it reaches the end it will go to main menu. Any tutorial for the dispatch events? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save your game as SWF and make another project with timeline-animated intro. When the intro ends, make your project to load your game. `Loader` class can load other swf files. So, you don't need to edit your game classes.

Comment: I haven't learnt anything about loading swf. can you please give me an example?

Comment: Ok, Here is [Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html)

Comment: @user3411184 There are some issues with loaded SWF and stage access, the loaded SWF has a separate stage and there's some security issue as well, so you'd better IMHO stick with one SWF, as it's a lot easier to debug. Also relocating game functionality from `Main` will eventually help you in planning class structure and potentially make your game expandable, should you desire to add a screen, for example.

Comment: thanks for explanation. I think so. having many .fla is confusing